# Where is the file *.NavData coming from?

Tags: git, jsf, netbeans

I have a Java EE 7 application with FlowSoped objects and use NetBeans.

Git shows me a new file: myFlowName-flow.NavData

*Where does it come from? What is this?*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Scene Scope="Project" version="2">
    <Scope Scope="Faces Configuration Only"/>
    <Scope Scope="Project"/>
    <Scope Scope="All Faces Configurations"/>
</Scene>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As illustrated by [this commit](https://java.net/projects/javaeetutorial/lists/commits/archive/2013-04/message/21), it is a generated file.

A typical JSF project should ignore it, as in [this `.gitignore`](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-faces/blob/master/.gitignore)